# How to remove null from Podio calculations (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, null, podio

I have simple Podio calculations field as follows to concatenate First+Middle+Last names together as Display Name.

First name +" "+ Middle name +" "+ Last name

Problem is that sometimes Middle name is empty followed that concatenated Display Name shows “null” instead of empty. First Name null Last Name.

How to remove/not show null in calculations field using Javascript? Podio calculations field accepts Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test whether the middle name is present or not. This should work:

First name +" "+ (Middle Name ? Middle Name : '') +" "+ Last name